# Crossdevice encoding static file to stream in browser using FFMPEG (segmented h264 ?)

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, streaming, html5-video, h.264

I'm building a mediacenter application in NodeJS which is going pretty ok. 
(you can check it out on Github: https://github.com/jansmolders86/mediacenterjs )

I'm using FFMPEG to transcode local (static) movies to a stream which I then send to the browser.

At first I used h264 with Flash which worked in browsers, but I really need it to work on Android an iOS (so no Flash) and preferably working on a Raspberry Pi.

But getting it to play on all devices is driving me absolutely insane!

I have all these bits of the puzzle I've gathered from countless hours reading articles, tutorials and stack overflow posts, which led me to the conclusion that I need to produce the following:

> - Use video codec H264 to transcode to MP4
> - Move the moovatom '-movflags' to make a MP4 streamable
> - Segment the stream so Apple can play the stream as well.

But getting nowhere with this. Every time I produce a series of FFMPEG settings that either don't work, or work on some devices rather than all.

Some of my failed attempt where:

My flash attempt -> **Main problem (not running in IOS):**

```
    '-y','-ss 0','-b 800k','-vcodec libx264','-acodec mp3'\ 
    '-ab 128','-ar 44100','-bufsize 62000', '-maxrate 620k'\
    metaDuration,tDuration,'-f flv
```

my HLS attempt -> **Main problem (not running in browser):**

```
        '-r 15','-b:v 128k','-c:v libx264','-x264opts level=41'\
        '-threads 4','-s 640x480','-map 0:v','-map 0:a:0','-c:a mp3'\
        '-b:a 160000','-ac 2','-f hls','-hls_time 10','-hls_list_size 6'\
        '-hls_wrap 18','-start_number 1'
```

My MP4 attempt -> **Main problem (duration is shortened and the later part of the video is speeding by)**

```
       '-y','-ss 0','-b 800k','-vcodec libx264','-acodec mp3'\
       '-ab 128','-ar 44100','-bufsize 62000', '-maxrate 620k'\
       metaDuration,tDuration,'-f mp4','-movflags','frag_keyframe+empty_moov'
```

Second MP4 attempt: -> **Main problem (duration is shortened and the later part of the video is speeding by)**

```
    '-y','-vcodec libx264','-pix_fmt yuv420p','-b 1200k','-flags +loop+mv4'\
    '-cmp 256','-partitions +parti4x4+parti8x8+partp4x4+partp8x8+partb8x8'\
    '-me_method hex','-subq 7','-trellis 1','-refs 5','-bf 3','-coder 1'\
    '-me_range 16','-g 150','-keyint_min 25','-sc_threshold 40'\
    '-i_qfactor 0.71','-acodec mp3','-qmin 10','-qdiff 4','-qmax 51'\
    '-ab 128k','-ar 44100','-threads 2','-f mp4','-movflags','frag_keyframe+empty_moov'])
```

Here is an example of the FFMPEG log running with these settings:

```
        file conversion error ffmpeg version N-52458-gaa96439 Copyright (c) 2000-2013 the FFmpeg developers
          built on Apr 24 2013 22:19:32 with gcc 4.8.0 (GCC)
          configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --e
        nable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable
        -libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --ena
        ble-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwola
        me --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libxavs --enabl
        e-libxvid --enable-zlib
          libavutil      52. 27.101 / 52. 27.101
          libavcodec     55.  6.100 / 55.  6.100
          libavformat    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
          libavdevice    55.  0.100 / 55.  0.100
          libavfilter     3. 60.101 /  3. 60.101
          libswscale      2.  2.100 /  2.  2.100
          libswresample   0. 17.102 /  0. 17.102
          libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
        [avi @ 02427900] non-interleaved AVI
        Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.1 : mono
        Input #0, avi, from 'C:/temp/the avengers.avi':
          Duration: 00:00:34.00, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1433 kb/s
            Stream #0:0: Video: cinepak (cvid / 0x64697663), rgb24, 320x240, 15 tbr, 15 tbn, 15 tbc
            Stream #0:1: Audio: pcm_u8 ([1][0][0][0] / 0x0001), 22050 Hz, mono, u8, 176 kb/s
        Please use -b:a or -b:v, -b is ambiguous
        [libx264 @ 02527c60] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX
        [libx264 @ 02527c60] profile High, level 2.0
        [libx264 @ 02527c60] 264 - core 130 r2274 c832fe9 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2013 - http://www.videolan.org/x26
        4.html - options: cabac=1 ref=5 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x133 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16
         chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=2 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_th
        reads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 we
        ightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=150 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=abr mbtree=1 bitrate=120
        0 ratetol=1.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=10 qpmax=51 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.41 aq=1:1.00
        Output #0, mp4, to 'pipe:1':
          Metadata:
            encoder         : Lavf55.3.100
            Stream #0:0: Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 320x240, q=10-51, 1200 kb/s, 15360 tbn, 15 tbc
            Stream #0:1: Audio: mp3 (i[0][0][0] / 0x0069), 44100 Hz, mono, s16p, 128 kb/s
        Stream mapping:
          Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (cinepak -> libx264)
          Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_u8 -> libmp3lame)
        Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
        frame=  106 fps=0.0 q=10.0 size=       1kB time=00:00:06.94 bitrate=   1.4kbits/s
        frame=  150 fps=149 q=14.0 size=       1kB time=00:00:09.87 bitrate=   1.0kbits/s
        frame=  191 fps=126 q=16.0 size=       1kB time=00:00:12.61 bitrate=   0.8kbits/s
        frame=  244 fps=121 q=16.0 size=    2262kB time=00:00:16.14 bitrate=1147.6kbits/s
        frame=  303 fps=120 q=14.0 size=    2262kB time=00:00:20.08 bitrate= 922.2kbits/s
        frame=  354 fps=117 q=15.0 size=    3035kB time=00:00:23.48 bitrate=1058.6kbits/s
        frame=  402 fps=113 q=15.0 size=    3035kB time=00:00:26.67 bitrate= 932.1kbits/s
        frame=  459 fps=113 q=16.0 size=    4041kB time=00:00:30.43 bitrate=1087.7kbits/s
        frame=  510 fps=103 q=2686559.0 Lsize=    5755kB time=00:00:33.93 bitrate=1389.3kbits/s

        video:5211kB audio:531kB subtitle:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.235111%
        [libx264 @ 02527c60] frame I:6     Avg QP:10.55  size: 25921
        [libx264 @ 02527c60] frame P:245   Avg QP:12.15  size: 14543
        [libx264 @ 02527c60] frame B:259   Avg QP:15.55  size:  6242
        [libx264 @ 02527c60] consecutive B-frames:  6.1% 73.7% 14.7%  5.5%
        [libx264 @ 02527c60] mb I  I16..4: 19.9%  6.2% 73.9%
        [libx264 @ 02527c60] mb P  I16..4:  6.0%  0.2% 12.0%  P16..4: 35.4%  9.6% 16.3%  7.0%  5.6%    skip: 7.8%
        [libx264 @ 02527c60] mb B  I16..4:  0.7%  0.0%  4.3%  B16..8: 27.6% 17.2% 17.0%  direct:17.3%  skip:15.9%  L0:39.4% L1:43.2%
        BI:17.4%
        [libx264 @ 02527c60] final ratefactor: 11.41
        [libx264 @ 02527c60] 8x8 transform intra:1.6% inter:4.0%
        [libx264 @ 02527c60] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 93.0% 97.0% 94.9% inter: 58.4% 58.7% 50.6%
        [libx264 @ 02527c60] i16 v,h,dc,p: 15% 26% 54%  5%
        [libx264 @ 02527c60] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 16% 17% 39%  4%  4%  3%  1%  6%  9%
        [libx264 @ 02527c60] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 28% 34% 21%  4%  2%  2%  2%  2%  5%
        [libx264 @ 02527c60] i8c dc,h,v,p: 51% 24% 19%  6%
        [libx264 @ 02527c60] Weighted P-Frames: Y:4.1% UV:1.2%
        [libx264 @ 02527c60] ref P L0: 68.2%  9.8% 11.0%  5.6%  4.6%  0.8%  0.0%
        [libx264 @ 02527c60] ref B L0: 87.7%  8.0%  3.9%  0.4%
        [libx264 @ 02527c60] ref B L1: 97.8%  2.2%
        [libx264 @ 02527c60] kb/s:1255.36
```

Lastly this is my node code fireing up FFMPEG. (I use the module Fluent-ffmpeg: https://github.com/schaermu/node-fluent-ffmpeg )

```
    var proc = new ffmpeg({ source: movie, nolog: true, timeout:15000})                         
        .addOptions(['-r 15','-b:v 128k','-c:v libx264','-x264opts level=41','-threads 4','-s 640x480','-map 0:v','-map 0:a:0','-c:a mp3','-b:a 160000','-ac 2','-f hls','-hls_time 10','-hls_list_size 6','-hls_wrap 18','-start_number 1 stream.m3u8'])
        .writeToStream(res, function(retcode, error){
            if (!error){
                console.log('file has been converted succesfully',retcode .green);
            }else{
                console.log('file conversion error',error .red);
            }
        });
```

**So to conclude this very long and code heavy question:**

I hope this does not come off as a lazy request, but could someone show/explain to me which FFMPEG settings could/should work on all platforms (modern browsers, Android and iOS) producing a stream of a static file which I can send to a HTML5 player.

**[EDIT] what I need if a generic option isn't available**

And if this is not possible as some posts might suggest, I would love to see a set of FFMPEG settings that get's the job done properly as far as mp4 streaming is concerned. (e.g encoding a streamable mp4).

The streaming mp4 needs the following

> - A shifted moovAtom
> - It needs to be h264

Thanks very much for your help!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no format that can play on every device and browser. HTML5  is getting us closer, but there is still debate on formats and codecs. My friends at Zencoder have a new blog post blog post ([HERE](http://blog.zencoder.com/2013/09/13/what-formats-do-i-need-for-html5-video/)) that addresses this exact issue.

EDIT: you asked for more specifics. Again, it depends on what platforms you wish to target. I will cover a couple here.

This should play on all modern browsers that support the h.264 codec. It should also play on iPhone4 and above:

```
ffmpeg -i ~/Dropbox/Test\ Content/bigbuckbunny/bigbuckbunny_1500.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -profile:v main -b:v 512k -s 1280x720 -r:v 30 -acodec libfdk_aac -b:a 128k -movflags faststart -y movie1.mp4
```

The iPhone 3gs does not support main profile, and its max supported resolution is 640x480. This command will encode for this older device.

```
ffmpeg -i ~/Dropbox/Test\ Content/bigbuckbunny/bigbuckbunny_1500.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -profile:v baseline -b:v 512k -s 640x432 -r:v 30 -acodec libfdk_aac -b:a 128k -movflags faststart -y movie2.mp4
```

I encoded some sample files and created a web page here:
http://szatmary.org/stackoverflow/18758133/

The HTML looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<br>ffmpeg -i ~/Dropbox/Test\ Content/bigbuckbunny/bigbuckbunny_1500.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -profile:v main -b:v 512k -s 1280x720 -r:v 30 -acodec libfdk_aac -b:a 128k -movflags faststart -y movie1.mp4<br>
<video controls>
  <source src="movie1.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
<br>ffmpeg -i ~/Dropbox/Test\ Content/bigbuckbunny/bigbuckbunny_1500.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -profile:v baseline -b:v 512k -s 640x432 -r:v 30 -acodec libfdk_aac -b:a 128k -movflags faststart -y movie2.mp4<br>
<video controls>
  <source src="movie2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Here the command broken down into what each element means:

command + input file (should be obvious):

```
ffmpeg -i ~/Dropbox/Test\ Content/bigbuckbunny/bigbuckbunny_1500.mp4
```

Use libx264 to encode the video:

```
-vcodec libx264
```

Set the h.264 profile to main. baseline will allow for playback on older devices, but you will sacrifice a little quality:

```
-profile:v main
```

Set the bitrate to 512 kilobits per second. Choose a value based on the available bandwidth. Higher for LAN/WiFi, lower for 3G/LTE

```
-b:v 512k
```

Scale the video to 720p resolution (Again depends on target platform)

```
-s 1280x720
```

Encode at 30 frames per second:

```
-r:v 30
```

Use libfdk_aac to encode the audio. Or use libmp3lame if you want mp3. AAC is highly recommended. It has much better support on ios and produces higher quality audio:

```
-acodec libfdk_aac
```

Set audio bitrate to 128 kilobits per second. You may adjust this for bandwidth as well. with AAC you can probably go as low as 32k

```
-b:a 128k
```

Set audio sampling rate to 48000 sample per second. If using mp3, do 44100 for ios

```
-r:a 48000
```

This tells ffmpeg to place the moov atom at be start of the mp4 file.

```
-movflags faststart
```

Output file (-y tells ffmpeg it can overwrite the file without asking)

```
-y movie1.mp4
```

Comment: Wauw Szatmary! This is exactly what I was looking for! I'll try it out later today and if it works for me. Thanks so far!

Comment: Again thanks for your answer Szatmary! I tried your settings and still have two issues. The first is that `-movflags faststart` gives me the `error muxer does not support non seekable putput`. I don't get this error with: `frag_keyframe+empty_moov`. The profile main gives me the `error: 'main profile doesn't support 4:4:4`.  if I use `high444` it does work though. So the video plays but still plays way to fast. Am I doing something stupendously wrong?

Comment: Ok, so you are transcoding on demand? What faststart does, is once the encoding is finished it writes the moov atom to the front of the file (instead of the end). It does this because the moov contains information about every frame.  Information it does not have until the encode is complete. the player can not play without reading the moov first. empty_moov is for encoding to DASH or Smooth Streaming. Formats that are not supported in ios. HLS is not supported in most browsers. So, what you are looking for does not exist.

Comment: You have two options. First use the commercial version of JW player to playback HLS in browsers that do not otherwise have support for HLS. Second. Look at the User-Agent string form the HTTP request, and serve FLV to flash, and HLS to IOS. (Or have the client put the desired encoding format in the URL e.g. http://mediacenter.js/file3?format=hls )

Comment: Oh, and add -pix_fmt yuv420p back in after -vcodec libx264. This is your raw video color format. I don't see 444 come up much, so I usually don't need to use it.

Comment: Thanks again for your time and answers! I'm nearly there please stick with me :). Yeah I'm transcoding on demand (or on the fly if you will). So if I want to do that I need HLS? Does that require any additional settings? I know you can segment a HLS stream. And HLS has several specific settings. Also which filetype should I use? m3u8? Or can I stick with mp4? Thanks again!

Comment: You must use m3u8 (ts) for ios. It will generate a lot of files (one constantly changing m3u8, and one ts per segment of video) that you must host over http.

Comment: Thank you or your knowlegde. I hope i can figure it out from here. You've realy earned the bounty! Thnx again

Comment: Sure thing. Feel free to email me directly if you need more details. Good luck on your project. I look forward to see it finished.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you won't find a setting which works on every device. I'd recommend you to check the user agent and then use different settings for different devices. This way you could also use device optimized settings.

Comment: I was afraid of that, but I think it is possible. A segmented mp4 stream would do the trick. But I would be a happy camper if I knew how to get a regular mp4 stream to work in the browser. Could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: you should do 2 things additionally. First deinterlace your video: http://sonnati.wordpress.com/2012/10/19/ffmpeg-the-swiss-army-knife-of-internet-streaming-part-vi/ and second use a baseline profile... see here: http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/x264EncodingGuide#Compatibility

Comment: Thanks that's really helpful information!

Can I encoding and deinterlace at the same time though? 
The whole idea of the project is that a local file can be streamed to a device in a matter of seconds. Hence I use the module 'Fluent-FFMPEG'. If I need to deinterlace the movie first before being able to stream it would defy it's purpose :)

Comment: How about just forgetting about node.js, flash etc. and just playing rtsp streams using a third party player, your already using ffmpeg which is the only disadvantage to that route.

Comment: Thanks! That could be a possibility as well, although I would have to figure out how to control this 3rd party server with node since the GUI is built on top on Node. And I doubt that would be an easy thing to pull off.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking about 2 workarounds to enable seeking. I'm assuming that, like me, you don't want to store files transcoded in advance.

The first one is just faking seek from the browser. Use a custom timeline control and when seeking change the video src to an URL including the desired start time, and pass it to ffmpeg. Of course this completely defeats browser prefetching. I implemented this in my project and it works fine.

The second option is a bit more technical and I'm not sure how to do it. The idea would be to transcode all available videos in advance, extract the moov atom, save it to disk and write it manually when streaming. This seems quite hard to do but not impossible.